# two divs side by side (again)

Tags: html, css

I have read countless posts on this topic however I am yet to find a solution that works. I simply want to have two divs side by side with the LHS div being the width of the FA char and the RHS div being the remainder.

```
<div class="helper">
  <div class="text-info"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x"></i></div>
  <div class="text-muted">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin non tincidunt ante. Duis a est ipsum. Morbi vulputate neque vitae nibh sodales gravida. Etiam viverra vulputate est nec faucibus. Nullam volutpat sagittis augue, et mattis nisi facilisis vel. Nunc eu dignissim lectus, vitae venenatis nisi. Proin euismod, enim nec pulvinar maximus, mi justo luctus odio, in tristique dolor augue nec lacus.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `display:table-cell` to your content and icon will give the desired output. Check below snippet.

```css
.inline {
  display: table-cell !important;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="helper">
  <div class="text-info"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x inline"></i></span>
    <div class="text-muted inline">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin non tincidunt ante. Duis a est ipsum. Morbi vulputate neque vitae nibh sodales gravida. Etiam viverra vulputate est nec faucibus. Nullam volutpat sagittis augue, et mattis nisi facilisis vel.
      Nunc eu dignissim lectus, vitae venenatis nisi. Proin euismod, enim nec pulvinar maximus, mi justo luctus odio, in tristique dolor augue nec lacus.
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you however this solution has the text wrapping which I want to avoid.

Comment: I don't find any word wrap, can you pls specific?

Comment: The text starts to the right of the icon however the second line of text is under the icon. I wish to have these two items in effectively two columns next to each other.

Comment: check the updated one. then you are suppose to use `display: table-cell`.

Comment: @RaJeshRiJo : Now you're just copying my answer, RaJesh :-p

Comment: @JohnSlegers not exactly, i just changed my answer as per his requirement. didn't copy from yours.

Comment: Oh well... I'm in a good mood, so +1 for you too then ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to do but you could use something like [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) which is in the JS fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/s9g7wjxw/).

Alternatively you could do something like this:

HTML

```
<div class="helper">
  <div class="text-info">FA</div>
   <div class="text-muted">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin non tincidunt ante. Duis a est ipsum. Morbi vulputate neque vitae nibh sodales gravida. Etiam viverra vulputate est nec faucibus. Nullam volutpat sagittis augue, et mattis nisi facilisis vel. Nunc eu dignissim lectus, vitae venenatis nisi. Proin euismod, enim nec pulvinar maximus, mi justo luctus odio, in tristique dolor augue nec lacus.
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.text-info, .text-muted {
  float:left;
}
.helper {
  clear:both;
}
```

If you want both of them to have different widths, you can simply set the widths of each (using `%`, `px` or whatever).

Comment: This did not work for me. Still places on div under the other.

Comment: Do you have any margin or padding on any of the containers? Because if you do, then you'd need to adjust the width because of the <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model">CSS box model</a>

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're going for :

```css
.text-muted {
  display: table-cell;
}

.text-info {
  padding-right: 10px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="helper">
  <div class="text-info"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x"></i></div>
  <div class="text-muted">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin non tincidunt ante. Duis a est ipsum. Morbi vulputate neque vitae nibh sodales gravida. Etiam viverra vulputate est nec faucibus. Nullam volutpat sagittis augue, et mattis nisi facilisis vel. Nunc eu dignissim lectus, vitae venenatis nisi. Proin euismod, enim nec pulvinar maximus, mi justo luctus odio, in tristique dolor augue nec lacus.
  </div>
</div>
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4Lgxnj4m/3/).

Comment: yes this should work. +1

Comment: This is the closest any of the suggested solutions have come. Is it possible to have the text closer to the top as it is currently stepped down due to the size of the FA icon?

Comment: @Dercni : You might want to try `float : left` for `.text-info` and `display: table-cell;` for `.text-muted`. See [**this demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/4Lgxnj4m/3/)!

Comment: @Dercni : I updated my answer in correspondence with your other requirements!